# How to get the visible dimensions of a scrollable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the visible height of a div and I can't find the way to do it.
http://jsfiddle.net/MVupa/1/

Even the library fracs:
http://larsjung.de/fracs/

Does not seem to give me the right number:
http://jsfiddle.net/MVupa/2/

Any ideas?

(End goal is to adjust an element max-height dynamically, depending on the window height.)

Answer (score 0):

this is what i came up with: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MVupa/4/)

```
$('.height').text($('.inner').height())
$('.scrollHeight').text($('.inner')[0].scrollHeight)
$('.inner').height($('.outer').height());
$('.visibleHeight').text($('.inner').height());
```

and you can set it to a `$(window)resize();` function.

Comment: I am on the step before I know what max-height to set the element to. At the example, it's easy, since there's just one child. But what if there are more? http://jsfiddle.net/MVupa/5/

Comment: There's no general solution for this, because it's not really possible (you could calculate the scroll position of the outer div, calculate heights of inner divs and work it out that way, but that seems a bit over the top). You have to calculate the correct size manually. For instance using @McMaster's example with multiple children, you'd minus off the height of all the children: http://jsfiddle.net/MVupa/7/